# eslint 'App' is assigned warning using with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, jshint

I don't see any problem with my code, App is a component and it's used, but eslint gave me this warning

```
./src/containers/app/index.js
  Line 6:  'App' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

my code

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux'
import store, { history } from './store'
import App from './containers/app'

import './index.css'

const target = document.querySelector('#root')

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <App />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  target
)
```

Any clue how to fix that for react?

Answer (score 0):

The standard ESLint rules don't know anything about JSX. You'll need to use https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-vars.md in order to get the behavior you want.